# Not able to start bin/zkCli.sh

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper. I did all the steps till bin/zkServer.sh

when I try to exectue this commend, i get error

bin/zkCli.sh
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain

I got some lead that ZooKeeperMain should be compiled. But I am not sure what to do on this.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache Zookeeper version on Github is not the compiled one. You have to compile the source in order to run the CLI script. Alternatively, you can download the released and compiled version from https://zookeeper.apache.org/releases.html#download

I had the same issue which you have when I was using zookeeper from Github. I switched to the released version and it worked without doing any extra step.